# How to fix customer display pole that displays garbage?

Tags: port, serial, point-of-sale

I have an Openbravo POS workstation with a customer display pole. The pole is VFD-860. When I click on the products on the Sales page of Openbravo, the display responds but displays garbage:
[image]

When I turn the pole off and then on. I get this:
[image]

So it is not exactly broken. Com port is correct because otherwise it would not respond at all.

There is a configuration utility with the pole but it is either the wrong version (it says it's for VFD660_460 but the documentation at http://bit.ly/iUbmpB says that VFD860 uses software which installs itself to Start menu > Programs > VFD-660_460) or there is some other problem because whatever choice I make there, after clicking Accept I always get Device Time Out error (even though I see another garbage character appearing onto the display the second I click Accept).

How to fix that?

Comment: How about contacting the vendor?

Comment: Have you tried using Telnet to test the display is working.

Comment: @DanBig. Email is sent. Waiting for reply.

Comment: @stukelly, Yes. Telnet does the same thing.

Comment: A different COM port also does the same thing (if I choose that other port from the settings)

Comment: Are you sure the serial port is also set to 9600,O,8,1? Odd parity is unusual. Are you sure the pole is supposed to be set to 9600,O,8,1? Again, odd parity is *very* unusual and a parity mismatch could cause this kind of problem.

Comment: David, you are right. The issue *was* caused by a parity mismatch. I had to change the parity in Windows to match the pole's current setting and then I was able to successfully reprogram the pole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you contact the vendor? It sounds like there is some kind of COM port issue, but really this is so specialized that your first point of contact would be your vendor's support line. I'm assuming you paid for the equipment, you should get some form of support.

Comment: I tried phoning but could not reach. I will try to email them.

Comment: I sent an email to manufacturer. Waiting for a reply..

Comment: After exchanging some emails with customer support I was successful and managed to get the customer display pole working. A first few attempts resulted in com port error but I think that by specifying the same settings in the Device Manager that I saw displayed on the pole itself, I was able to successfully reprogram the pole. Then I changed Windows port settings back to defaults and now it works.